# What's the best way of implementing a buffer of fixed size when using fread in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, fread

Suppose that you have a file of integers and you want to read them one by one.

You have two options for buffering.

1. Declare an array `buffer` of size `N` and use `setvbuf` to tell `fread` which buffer to use. Then when calling the function `fread` to read an integer you write `fread(&myInt, sizeof(myInt), 1, inputFile);`
2. Declare the same array `buffer` but this time don't use the function `setvbuf`. Instead work on the buffering by yourself. So call `fread(buffer, bufferSize*sizeof(int), 1, inputFile)`

From my understanding `setvbuf` exists to make your life easier, but does it come at a cost? Which method would you use in terms of performance?

Comment: My question would be why are you using `fread` in C++?

Comment: Personally, I tend to just write my own I/O classes on top of the `open`, `read`, and `write` system calls, since I don't like the interface of `stdio` *or* `iostream`

Comment: The whole point of stdio (and iostream) is that you let the system do the buffering for you. Simply read as many octets as you need using `fread` or `getc`, and stdio will make sure that OS-level reads are buffered. `setvbuf` is only for the rare occasions when you want to manage the buffer size/allocation yourself. Rule of thumb: if you need to ask whether you need `setvbuf`, you don't.

Comment: NetVipeC, for testing purposes, I wouldn't use it otherwise in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use neither of your examples.  I don't think that part of the I/O is the performance bottleneck.

The `vbuf` is an area for the input routine to place data before putting it into your destination.  It could be used as a cache or as a preformatting buffer.

Most of the time, I/O bottlenecks are related to the quantity of data fetched and the number of fetches.  For example, reading one byte at a time is less efficient than reading a block of bytes.

Another I/O related bottleneck is the duration between input requests.  I/O devices prefer to keep streaming data, non-stop.  Some input devices, like hard drives, have an overhead time between when the request is received and when the data starts transmitting.  For hard drives, this would be the disk speed up time.

Your best performance is not to waste development time messing with the C or C++ libraries.  You need to use hardware assist.  Some platforms have a device called a Direct Memory Access controller (DMA).  This device can take data from an input source and deliver it to memory without using the CPU.  The CPU can be executing instructions while the DMA is transferring data.  In order to use hardware assistance, you need to write code at the OS driver level, or access the OS drivers directly.

The C and C++ I/O libraries are designed for a platform independent concept called streams.  There may be execution overhead associated with this (such as extra buffering).  If you don't care about different platforms, then access the OS drivers directly.

Don't waste your time messing with the C and C++ libraries.  Not much performance gain there.  More performance lies in accessing the OS drivers directly (or using your own).  How and when you access the I/O will show bigger performance gains than tweaking the C and C++ libraries.

Lastly, using the processors data cache effectively will gain you performance too.

Comment: "speed up time"?  Perhaps you meant "spin up"?

Comment: Also, switching from the C++ `<fstream>` to the C (and C++) `<stdio.h>` helps... so much it is surprising.  But yes, direct use of OS APIs such as `mmap` beats `<stdio.h>` by a wide margin as well.

Comment: I don't know what gives you the idea that DMA won't happen through the usual usermode APIs and wrappers, though.

Comment: I don't understand why create the fstream when you have stdio. C is also a part of C++ right? Then why not use stdio and decide to create something that performs really badly against the equivalent version in C?

Comment: @BenVoigt:  Not all platforms have DMA.  Some platforms may have DMA and not use it.  It's not standard and use of DMA depends on the OS or device drivers.  It's also a resource that needs sharing.

Comment: @jsguy: There is value to being able to override `operator<<` for new types.  Extensibility is a big advantage of the C++ API.  But the performance is miserable, and so is the lack of separation of concerns.  There's a lot of discussion going on around doing it better.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: But if your platform has drivers that make use of DMA, then the implementations of POSIX, C, and C++ file access APIs will be built on top of those drivers.  "In order to get DMA" is not a valid reason for applications to switch to OS-specific APIs.